# no module named pycountry

Tags: python, module

Attempting to import and use pycountry in python 2.7.

```
import pycountry
len(pycountry.countries)
```

However,  module is not recognised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):       
File "countries_list.py", line 1, in <module>                                    
import pycountry                     
ImportError: No module named pycountry
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to install it using **pip**.

```
pip install pycountry
```

And then you can use it :)

Comment: Thanks! Receive errors when attempt to install.

Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

Comment: If you are not using a virtualenv, you can install de package with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looked thru several articles and youtube videos but none got my pycharm fixed to recognize the pycountry module until I tried executing the program in the pycharm IDE terminal and then the pycharm EDE started to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using python 3.9 and sublime text. Once installed pycountry with pip

> pip instal pycountry

Sublime text didn't recognise the module.
The problem/solution was to install python 3 interpreter with

> Command Palete -> Package Control: Install Package

Once I did pycountry module works!